# Can I call delete on primitives?

Tags: c++, templates, destructor, delete-operator

I have a templated class, myFoo, which stores "stuff" of type T which can be either primitive or pointers to complex types. When myFoo is deleted, I want to release all the memory associated with everything it happens to be storing. This means I need to call delete on every pointer being stored but I might also end up calling delete on a primitive. Is this safe??

I've included a sketch of myFoo below to better highlight what's going on. I'm not sure if the behaviour of the destructor is well defined.

```
template<class T>
class myFoo
{
   public:
       myFoo(int size) 
       { 
          size_ = size;
          T* foo = new T[size_]; 
       }

       void addFoo(T tmp, int index) 
       {
             foo[index] = tmp;
       }

       virtual ~myFoo()
       {
           for(int i=0; i < size_; i++)
           {
               delete foo[i];
           }
           delete [] foo;
       }

  private:
      int size_;
      T* foo;
}
```

Comment: Can't you specialize for pointers?

Comment: As written, your code doesn't make sense for *any* type `T`, at least semantically: You're mixing up ownership responsibilities, and the class would be a usability, readability and maintainability nightmare. In short, it shouldn't be *your* concern what `T` is, and the client should do her own cleaning up (or of course use a smart pointer).

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm writing a database of sorts. I want to insert data into it. It makes sense for the database to take ownership of the memory of stuff I'm storing inside it. Otherwise I'd need to manage all the data from the database externally. It's a bit "wtf??" if I do it as you suggest.

Comment: What's "wtf??" about using smart pointers?  I assume the reason you're storing pointers for complex types is because they are too heavy to be copying around?  Let the client decide whether his type is too heavy.  If it is, he can make T a smart pointer, then you don't need to worry about deleting.

Comment: Besides, this line `T* foo = new T[size_];` isn't doing what you want. It creates a *local* pointer in the constructor, and immediately leaks the memory when you leave the constructor.

Comment: As a simple rule, a class should contain at most one manually-managed resource, and be fully responsible for that. That means `new` and `delete` should be matched. This is a clear violation of that rule: there are two `delete`s in this class, one of which doesn't match a `new`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you can call `delete` on is a pointer type. It's an error to call `delete` on an `int`, for example. If you arrange your templates so that your code tries to do something that is an error, the compiler will let you know and refuse to compile your code.

So no, you don't have to worry about "accidentally" deleting a non-pointer.

Comment: So how could I achieve the behaviour I describe?

Comment: You could have different templates depending on whether you wanted to store pointers or not. Or, you could store instances of a smart pointer class, and rely on the destructor of the smart pointer to do the deleting.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I think you (and others) have convinced me that smart pointers are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Template specialization

```
template <class T> struct delete_it;

template <class T> struct delete_it<T*>
{
   static void func(T* ptr) { delete ptr; }
};

template <> struct delete_it<int>
{
   static void func(int) {}
};

template <> struct delete_it<double>
{
   static void func(double) {}
};
```

Repeat for all primitive types. Then

```
   virtual ~myFoo()
   {
       for(int i=0; i < size_; i++)
       {
           delete_it<T>::func(foo[i]);
       }
       delete [] foo;
   }
```

Unchecked code.