# Deallocating (and calling a destructor of) a template argument

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation

**Context**

I'm trying to implement my version of the `std::vector` template class. The vector contains a dynamic array of the template argument `T`:

```
_vec = new T[n];
```

Obviously `T` can be any type at all, pointers, classes, primitive types. When one call `v.resize(4)` on a vector of size `6` it should obviously remove the last 2 elements of the dynamic array (without reallocating the array) following [this specification](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/):

> If n is smaller than the current container size, the content is reduced to its first n elements, removing those beyond (and destroying them).

By *destroying* I mean, and I think the std library means, calling the destructor for object or simply deallocating the memory space if it is any other primitive type including pointers.

**Question:** Is it possible (and if so, how) destroy template elements in a dynamically allocated array without deallocating and reallocating it?

**What have I tried?** Well, I sincerely don't know where to start:

- Apparently [you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11643420/493122) call a `delete` on primitive types.
- [You can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855977/493122) explicitly call a destructor on an object, but that wouldn't work if `T` is not an object.
- I thought of just decreasing the internal `_size` counter (so that an a future `push_back` the elements would be overwritten), but that wouldn't immediately call the destructor for the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are implementing a `vector`, you probably want to keep the management of the storage and the management of the objects separate.

Storage is managed using `allocator::allocate(size_type n)` and `allocator::deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)`, which are typically implemented as `return ::operator new(n * sizeof (T));` and `::operator delete(p);` respectively.

These functions allocate and deallocate memory, but do not call constructors or destructors for objects contained in that memory.

Object lifetimes are managed using `allocator::construct(U* p, Args&&... args);` and `allocator::destroy(U* p);`, which are typically implemented as `::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` and `p->~U()` respectively.

These functions construct and deconstruct objects in preallocated memory, but do not themselves manage the memory.

Answer (score 1):

`new T[n]` is not what you want, because that will already create `n` *objects* of type `T`, but you only want to allocate *memory* for up to `n` objects of type `T`.

You may want to read up on placement-new syntax and placement-delete syntax. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)

Comment: For `std::vector`, I'm pretty sure that the standard dictates that you use the `construct` and `destroy` functions in the allocator rather than explicitly using placement-new and explicit-destructor-calls.

Comment: You are right, but if Jueecy does this just for fun, allocators are probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

FredOverflow is right about object allocation.

According your question, all you need to do is just distinguish objects from non-objects (scalars). There is a real code from `<xmemory>` in Visual Studio 2010 distribution:

```
template<class _Alloc> inline void _Destroy_range(
  typename _Alloc::pointer _First, typename _Alloc::pointer _Last, _Alloc& _Al);

template<class _Alloc> inline void _Destroy_range(
  typename _Alloc::pointer _First, typename _Alloc::pointer _Last, _Alloc& _Al, 
  _Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag);  // Object overload

template<class _Alloc> inline void _Destroy_range(
  typename _Alloc::pointer _First, typename _Alloc::pointer _Last, _Alloc& _Al, 
  _Scalar_ptr_iterator_tag);  // Non-object overload
```

They use simple dispatching with a special flag, which can be computed using some traits class.